# Compile member list of people who were sent to a specific Journey Builder activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

We have a number of decision splits in our journey. I am looking to build an audience list of everyone who exited after failing a specific decision split.

I know each activity has a unique ID so how do I query the table to find out the ID for that exit (As it doesn't show in the UI).  Once I have that activityID, how do I query to get the total population of the Activity?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve all the activities information and journey metadata information using the REST API. See example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionById.htm)

However, I don't think there is any API to retrieve the audience list for a particular activity in a journey.
To get the audience list who have exited after a specific decision split, follow the below steps

1. Create a boolean field **ExistedAfterDecisionSplit** in your entry source DE
2. In Contact Builder->Data Designer, create a new attribute group and link your entry source DE to the Contact key using a 1:1 relationship.
3. Create an update activity after that the specific decision split, choose the entry source DE from the wizard and updated the boolean field "ExistedAfterDecisionSplit" to true. This field will be true for all contacts who have exited after that specific decision split.
4. Now you can create a filter DE on your entry source DE with filter criteria **ExistedAfterDecisionSplit = true** and target those contacts.